# ddrescue goes very slow on encountering errors

Tags: ddrescue

I am using the ddrescue for the very first time.May be an expert with this can help me a little.

I have a 320 gb sata harddisk with 334 bad sectors(including 114 on the surface itself) & many thousands read errors. So it is about to fail anytime soon. I want to recover a partition of 280gb from the drive & `ddrescue` done a great job in the starting. It recovered 70 gb at a very fast speed of avg. 2500kb/s. but when it encountered multiple errors, it started running at as low as 1500 b/s. At this rate it would take a year to complete. So I stopped it, restarted live cd of parted magic & then restarted it from 80gb location by using `-i` option. It again started at very much faster rate & copied 10 gb data & then again when it encountered errors, it came to low speed

So it happens always. I am already using the `-O` option, but it is also not successful in increasing the speed.

I was thinking that if there is any program that can physically locate the bad sectors on the  disk partition without further damaging this failing disk, then I can run the `ddrescue` on the good sectors range only with the help of `-i` & `-s` options at a very fast rate, but I don't find any tool like this.

I am currently using the above command & it has copied total 110 gb data in the two days with some 3mb of error size.

```
ddrescue -d -n -N -O -vv /dev/sda5 krishna.img radhe.logfile
```

Please help me finding any solution for this. Any type of suggestion is highly welcomed.

Comment: I'm currently struggling with a failing disk also. I'm using Ontrack EasyRecovery Professional and some actions take time, I almost canceled restore because it was taking to long but then it got normal again. To see what bad sectors you've got try using HDD Regenerator, free version lets you check for bad sectors but doesn't repair anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-O` and `-a` options, something like `-O -a 2400000` in your case.  The combination will reopen the device when it slow reads as well as when it errors on read.  You may even find that the average rate goes up.  In which case you can stop and up the `-a` value to get to a happier place.